# How to shutdown an Ubuntu VM for 5 mins and then restart after 5 min automatically

Tags: shutdown, virtualization, restart

I would like to shutdown a VM which is running Ubuntu 12.04LTS, and bring it up again after 5 mins.

Can this be done using command line ?

Comment: That depends on the host OS running the VM.

Comment: Procedures and commands **considerably** depend on the host OS, and the virtualization software used. Please [edit] your question for this information. To give you a good answer we also need to know whether (and eventually why) your guest Ubuntu needs to shutdown/reboot, or if pausing it was good enough too.

Answer (score 1):

This answer is for ubuntu. It won't run if your host os is Windows ([as muru said](https://askubuntu.com/questions/503105/how-to-shutdown-a-ubuntu-vm-for-5-mins-and-then-restart-after-5-min-automaticall/503107#comment676280_503105)).

I would suggest:

`watch -n 300 <yourvmcommand> && sleep 300 && pkill <yourvmprocessname>`

The `watch` command will repeat every 300 secs the following:

1. Start the vm. If it started successfully then:
2. Wait 300 seconds. If it did wait 300 seconds then:
3. Kill the vm

Then watch takes over and will wait the 300 secs, then launch it again.

Comment: Thank you for reply. Actually I am doing this experiment on GENI resources. I dont have a control access to the resource. Only i can do is ssh. When i issue the command " sudo reboot" it reboots and comes up 30secs. What I want is "sudo reboot" command should take longer time to come up say 5mins.

Comment: so what about `sudo shutdown 5`?